# Dialogflow CX import entities using C#

Tags: c#, .net, dialogflow-cx

Unfortunately there is no API sample for c# to push entity type from an Dotnet project. Is there anyone working with it?? A sample code will be helpful.

Comment: Hello Zia. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.Cx.V3/latest/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.Cx.V3.EntityTypesClient) for Dialogflow CX `EntityTypesClient` C# API reference. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanx for the link, But already seen it, Can give me a sample if possible, couldn't figure out the way to use json key to authenticate and send a request. V3 has changed lot dew to support CX

Comment: Hello Zia. Referring to the EntityType API reference [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/entity), I could see C# sample code is not available for EntityTypesClient. If you would like to have your requirement as a feature, you can raise a feature request in [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/new?component=956347&template=1504477). Please note there would be no ETA on when the feature will be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [google-cloud-dotnet](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet) github has a set of [snippets](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/main/apis/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.Cx.V3/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.Cx.V3.Snippets) that have examples of using the CX API in C#, including one that shows List, Get, Create, Update, and Delete for [EntityTypes](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.Cx.V3/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.Cx.V3.Snippets/EntityTypesClientSnippets.g.cs).